# How to add a mean column based on user ID and session ID in R?

Tags: r, mean

I would like to ask a question regarding coding.

I have datasets and it has a session Id, User Id, and the target column which is the sales each session.
Here is a sample of what I have

[image]

```
dataset <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, USERID = c(500L, 520L, 500L, 530L, 530L, 
    520L, 520L, 520L), SALES = c(1000L, 1450L, 1390L, 1778L, 1966L, 
    1100L, 700L, 900L), Mean = c(1000, 1450, 1195, 1778, 1872, 1275, 
    1083.33, 1037.5)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to create a column for the mean for each session based on the specific user sessions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done with `group_by` from `dplyr` together with `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  group_by(USERID) %>%
  mutate(Mean = cumsum(SALES)/(1:n()))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   USERID [3]
     ID USERID SALES  Mean
  <int>  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1    500  1000 1000 
2     2    520  1450 1450 
3     3    500  1390 1195 
4     4    530  1778 1778 
5     5    530  1966 1872 
6     6    520  1100 1275 
7     7    520   700 1083.
8     8    520   900 1038.
```

```
dataset <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, USERID = c(500L, 520L, 500L, 530L, 530L, 
    520L, 520L, 520L), SALES = c(1000L, 1450L, 1390L, 1778L, 1966L, 
    1100L, 700L, 900L)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It appears that what @Ahmad is looking for is the mean by USERID where each row is calculated as if the rows bellow it do not exist.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you are right @DanielO. That should be doable.

Comment: I just saw your updated Answer after I posted my answer, It's a bit more elegant than mine.

Comment: I always appreciate a base R solution. People upvote tidyverse, so that's what I post.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @IanCampbell 
Can I ask you please another question ? 
I want to create a new column to show the number of days since the last purchase per User Id.

Comment: I would need to be able to see more of your data to answer that. Unless you are being blocked by the system, you should be able to ask a new question. When you ask the new question, be sure to provide your data in a usable form by pasting the output of `dput(head(data))` into your question.

Comment: @IanCampbell I am trying to use the same code to calculate the mean with the exception of the current raw value. 
I tried mutate(Mean = cumsum(SALES)/(1:n-1())). It did not work. 
Do you have a solution for this issue. 
I want to calculate the mean by USERID where each row is calculated as if the rows bellow and the current row are not known.

Comment: You could use `lag`, something like `mutate(Mean = cumsum(lag(SALES,default = 0))/(lag(1:n(),default = 1)))`. Maybe open a new question next time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do next time.

Answer (score 2):

This works in base-R

```
dataset$Mean <- sapply(1:nrow(dataset), function(x) mean(dataset$SALES[1:x][dataset$USERID[1:x]==dataset$USERID[x]]))

  ID USERID SALES     Mean
1  1    500  1000 1000.000
2  2    520  1450 1450.000
3  3    500  1390 1195.000
4  4    530  1778 1778.000
5  5    530  1966 1872.000
6  6    520  1100 1275.000
7  7    520   700 1083.333
8  8    520   900 1037.500
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this works as well

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[, Mean := cumsum(SALES)/seq_len(.N), USERID]
```

#### data

```
dataset <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, USERID = c(500L, 520L, 500L, 530L, 530L, 
    520L, 520L, 520L), SALES = c(1000L, 1450L, 1390L, 1778L, 1966L, 
    1100L, 700L, 900L)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```